# is it possible to deploy azure functions and app services on same domain?

Tags: azure, hosting, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I want single url for Azure functions as well as app services, No different urls needed. Can we host them both with the single domain url ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you want this?https://www.wintellect.com/host-website-azure-functions-node-js-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

As both Azure Functions and App Service instance names are globally unique, you can't deploy both into a single instance, like others have already mentioned.

However, using a single URL entry point is possible without introducing additional Azure resources. Azure Functions Proxy is the key component here.

Therefore, set Azure Functions instance as the main entry point and configure `proxies.json` in the Functions instance to point your Azure App Service endpoints. Then you'll have a single entry point for both Azure Functions and Azure App Service.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot deploy. But...

1) You could 'CNAME' them to use a subdomain.

Ex:

example.com --> App Services

fn.example.com --> Azure Functions

2) Another way is to use Azure Application Gateway's Route By Url feature.

example.com --> App Services

example.com/function --> Azure Functions

Answer (score 0):

The default hostname while creating App Service or Azure Function is ***your-app-name.azurewebsites.net***

Name have to be unique for App service or Azure function while creating. So you cannot have single URL for App Service and Azure Function .It will differ in the name .

But if you want to access App Service and Azure function by single URL, you can put **[Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-traffic-manager)** in front of App service and Azure Function and apply the **[Custom Domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name)** on Traffic manager URL and configure the back end pools as App service and Azure Function in Traffic Manager.